# Possible values for complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi can somebody help me with this: Consider the polynomial $p(z) = (z-r_1)^{a_1}(z-r_2)^{a_2}$. Assume that all roots of $p(z)$ are distinct, and let $\gamma$ be a closed rectifiable curve in $\mathbb{C}$ that does not pass through any of the roots of $p$. Find, with justification, all possible values for
    $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{p(z)}.$$
I have written it as partial fraction: 
Let $a_1=m, a_2=n$, writing as partial fractions, we have:
            $$\frac{1}{p(z)}=\frac{R_1}{(z-r_1)}+\cdots+\frac{R_m}{{(z-r_1)}^{m}}+\frac{R_{m+1}}{(z-r_2)}+\cdots+\frac{R_{m+n}}{{(z-r_2)}^{n}}$$
        which leads to
        $$\begin{aligned}
  &R_1(z-r_1)^{m-1}(z-r_2)^n+R_2(z-r_1)^{m-2}(z-r_2)^n+\ldots+R_m(z-r_2)^n\\
  &+R_{m+1}(z-r_2)^{n-1}(z-r_1)^m+R_{m+2}(z-r_2)^{n-2}(z-r_1)^m+\ldots+R_{m+n}(z-r_1)^m=1\ldots(\ast)
  \end{aligned}$$
But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: I don't think you need all that work, seems to me like there are 3 options, do you see why?

Comment: Ohh? I don't see it. I just learn this thing. I did the partial fraction because I saw an example which the roots are all different.

Comment: Do you know the residue-theorem?

Comment: So basically if both roots lie outside the curve, then the integral is 0. Correct? That is 1 possibility.

Comment: hmm, i meant four solutions :)

Comment: No, I have not learn that. I just learn Cauchy integral and winding number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interior of the closed curve will contain either $z_1,z_2$, both or neither. If the curve encompasses neither, the integral is zero by Cauchy. If the curve only contains $z_1$, for example, then

$$\int_{\gamma} \dfrac{1}{p(z)} \   dz = \int_{\gamma} \dfrac{1/(z-z_2)^{a_2}}{(z-z_1)^{a_1}} \   dz = \dfrac{2\pi i}{(a_1-1)!}\dfrac{d^{a_1-1}}{dz^{a_1-1}}\dfrac{1}{(z-z_2)^{a_2}}\Big{|}_{z=z_1}$$

See [Cauchy's Integral Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) for more.

Comment: If the curve contain both $z_1, z_2$, then what will be the values of the integral?

Comment: You separate the curve $\gamma$ into $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$. One around $z_1$, one around $z_2$ (each small enough to not contain both)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try that then =)